# catching all "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have a large swift project getting many data from JSON.

It is so hard to check every single peace of data whether it is nil or not.

Is there a way to catch all these nils so that my application will not crash when it get unexpected nils? Or I have to use "if let variable = ...." in all data I have!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bad news: yes, you should always check for optionals.

The good news: there are shortcuts that are more practical than `if let`. E.g. you can provide reasonable defaults (with the "*nil-coalescing operator*").

```
let itemID = jsonData["itemID"] as? NSNumber ?? 0
let stringVariable = jsonData["name"] as? String ?? ""
```

Also, note that you can list dependent `if let` statements without nesting:

```
if let person = jsonData["person"] as? [String: AnyObject],
   let name = person["name"] as? String { 
      // process name
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful